# Incomplete list of BLE GATT services discovered in Android HCI log is returned in getServices()

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, hci

I am connecting to a BLE device with custom firmware and 4 services, 2 of which are custom services that each have one custom characteristic.

When using discoverServices() after a successful connect, 4 services are found in the HCI log (see Wireshark screen below).

[image: Wireshark HCI log]

But only 3 services are returned from getServices() in my own Android code and in the nRF Bluetooth app, and the third service is missing its only characteristic:

[image]

The 4th service and its characteristic are nowhere to be found.

Longer HCI log of all activity after the connection event, including a characteristic read of one of the visible characteristics, is linked here:
[HCI log subset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lgtKiAxdA6EFlS8zzzxk8K_T2a6OUvMW)

Comment: Maybe you could post the whole hci log? Now we only see the first part where the services are discovered (and not the packet contents). Also, have you tried another phone or tablet?

Comment: @Emil link added. Around 10 phones have been tried total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In packet 54, there is a Read By Type Response. The content is an item "Attribute Data" containing handle 0x0211 and value 00. This value (00) is invalid. A characteristic declaration must have the following value components:

- Characteristic Properties (1 byte), Bit field of characteristic properties
- Characteristic Value Handle (2 bytes), Handle of the Attribute containing the value of this characteristic
- Characteristic UUID (2 or 16 bytes), 16-bit Bluetooth UUID or 128-bit UUID for Characteristic Value

So the value should be in total either 5 or 19 bytes. Your value is 1 byte.

Comment: We are using the PAN1026 Bluetooth Module. Do you have any idea why the module would respond incorrectly to the Read By Type Request?

Comment: Nope, I'm not familiar with that module.